# Having 2 images of diffrent sizes depending on screen size with fancybox

Tags: jquery, fancybox

I am trying to use fancybox as a lightbox to show images on a website.

I am designing the site to be a fixed width 960px site. I want to show images to people but also have larger images if the screen can show them.

a bit like how facebook deliver different size images to the user.

Fancybox will scale the images down if the window is to small to show them at fullsize, so I was thinking how can I use fancybox with 2 images.

one image would be 960px wide and be for users that have a screen 960px and smaller
(scaled down by fancybox)

and I'd have another image thats 1200+ wide for screens over 960px

If your screen can show 1100 pixels then you'll get the bigger image scaled down.

The reason for this is so smaller screen users don't have to download the big image.
with this bar set, I could put out images that are 1500 wide etc.

also I had looked at floatbox
http://floatboxjs.com/demo
but decided that some of the features of fancybox are better apart from one thing, floatbox has a feature to zoom into a picture if its not being shown at fullsize. see the earth picture demo, or open one of the other images in a small window. can fancybox do this? I know you can do this with a button but was wondering how to do it like floatbox does. while still letting the user save the image.

I have looked at other ways to do this with css, having images swap out etc but the way i am getting the content onto a page this won't work. also if you want to save the image it saves the smaller one for some reason. - http://csswizardry.com/2011/07/responsive-images-right-now/

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

If you use fancybox v2.x then you can have the same big image "scaled" to fit into the viewport for whatever resolution you have and then use the `buttons` helper to expand the image to its original (big) size.

Check the demo at http://fancyapps.com/fancybox/#docs, Extended functionality == > Button helper (don't forget to check the javascript tab)

Comment: "The reason for this is so smaller screen users don't have to download the big image."